# JavaScript not working when embedded via the url bar of browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to add this line to the url bar of the browser (my browser is Chrome)

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML+="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='st1.css'>";
```

When I press enter, the whole page disappears.

When I check the source code, I can see that the JavaScript was executed, but, the whole content disappears, though the content of the body stays the same in the source code !

Why is that happening?

Comment: Maybe the style sheet you're embedding has a rule that is hiding the body?

Comment: Use the devtools' DOM inspector and tell us what you see.

Comment: This works for me: `javascript:(function (){}(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML+="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='st1.css'>"));`

Comment: the new css file contains only a rule to change <td> background style ONLY, and has no rule that modify the body
the DOM inspector shows the following :
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='st1.css'> => added in the head section
and the body remains the SAME .. and every thing inside of it is the same, all the content ..

Comment: Panav Kapoor , your answer really worked .. thank you .. if you put it in a separate answer .. i'd rate it for you :)

Comment: @user1283226 : Answered :)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript you have written returns `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`

To make sure that there is no return value, change the code to something like this :

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML+="<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='st1.css'>";}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess innerHTML is only for displaying it in the webpage and not for adding anything in the headers.

Precisely you can't use that to do anything in the  section.

Comment: Are you guessing or do you know it?

Comment: innerHTML has done the task .. and added the css link successfully

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the statement doesn't return anything — anything that is deemed to be returnable in the expression will be taken as a URL or page content to replace the current page. Te expression `+=` will by default. A good solution is to precede the statement with `void` such that nothing is returned.